# Manage scaling of Statefulsets using Kubernetes API

Tags: kubernetes, containers, microservices, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-apiserver

- I want scale up my statefulset and want to initiate this scale up from inside the pod(container) using
  the Kubernetes API(http request) to the kubernetes rest server.
- I tried scaling up statefulset pods using

> PUT /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/statefulsets/{name}/scale

- but it didn't work for me.

Even tried fetching the scale data of specified statefulset using

> "GET /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/statefulsets/{name}/scale"

> REQUEST : curl -s -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X GET https://kubernetes.default.svc:443/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/$Namespace/$Kind/$PodNamePrefix/scale

Gives an error :

- "message": "statefulsets.apps "app-4x" is forbidden: User
  "system:serviceaccount::default" cannot get resource
  "statefulsets/scale" in API group "apps" in the namespace
  ""","reason": "Forbidden",
- Reference : https://v1-14.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: error mesaage state that service account do not have permission to view the statefulsets. ask your kubernetes administrator  to assign permission to this service account

Comment: @DashrathMundkar yes there was some permission issue regarding the service account. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) using `Role` and `RoleBinding` to authorize the service account to perform the required operations

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: ss-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["statefulsets/scale" ]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "create"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: ss-rolebinding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ss-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
```

Above `Role` and `RoleBinding` is based on the assumption that you are using `default` service account of `default` namespace to scale `statefulsets` in `default` namespace.